# Cocoa pods error with Google maps

Tags: swift, google-maps, cocoa, cocoapods

I download a git repositorie. It uses google maps. When I compiled the project, the project shows 160 errors.
I already try to update, change version of maps, install, gem update
Maybe its a problem with the podfile.

**Podfile**:

```
  # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
  source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
  platform :ios, '9.0'
  target 'FamilyNexus' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
 use_frameworks!
 # Pods for Myapp
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
 pod 'Firebase/Database'
 pod 'GoogleMaps'
 pod 'GooglePlaces'
 pod 'SideMenu'
 pod 'Alamofire'
 pod 'AlecrimCoreData', :git =>    'https://github.com/Alecrim/AlecrimCoreData.git', :branch => 'develop'

target 'MyappTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Alamofire'
end

target 'MyappUITests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Alamofire'
end
end
```

[image: Error image]

Comment: remove use_frameworks! and Alamofire

Comment: Doesnt works :(

Answer (score 0):

Was a error with version.

I downgrade version of google maps pod to   `pod 'GoogleMaps', '2.1.0'`